# Which option is correct?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect

1. I started cooking
2. I have started cooking

I don't quite understand the difference between the two options. Are both correct? Is okay to use two verbs in the same sentence, one following the other in two different tenses?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to use two verbs in one sentence - doesn't that happen in your language?

Comment: Thank you :D And yes, but in a different way. That is why is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The first would be used when describing something that happened sometime in the unspecified past.

The second could be talking about either your present condition, pretty much equivalent to "I am cooking right now" or it could be used to mean that you are starting to learn to cook as an ongoing thing (even if you are not engaged in cooking right this moment).